# Edit the toobarItems of topViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change dinamycally the ToolbarItems of my topviewcontroller.

I have a class that does my business logic and as a result returns an array of uibarbuttonitem.
so, i get the reference of the topviewcontroller like this:

```
ViewController *topVC = [appDelegate.navController topViewController];
```

now if i try to do:

```
[topVc setToolbarItems: myArrayofUibarbuttonItems];
```

But nothing happens.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could do it with the setItems function

```
[topVc.toolbar setItems:theArray];
```

just typed, not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
[topVc.navigationController setToolbarItems:myArrayofUibarbuttonItems];
```

this should help u.. happy coding :)